# Como puedo quitar valores de un string en Dart (Flutter)

Tags: string, flutter, dart

Tengo una app que me lee códigos de barra con el plugin ScanBarcodeRes, lo hace bien y lo guardo en una base de datos bien, pero los códigos que leeré en la app, tienen dos valores que necesito eliminar en la app, el codigo tiene esta estructura "19/56565-D4" por ejemplo.

Pues quiero eliminar el "/" y el "-", para guardarlo en la base de datos mysql asi 1956565D4, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con una expresión regular o también con el método `replaceAll` de `String`.

```
 final value = "19/56565-D4";
 final newValue = value.replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll("-", "");
 print("value: $newValue");
```

Comment: Gracias compañero me sirvio